# Homogeneous ideals of graded rings

Tags: commutative-algebra

Consider the ring $R=k[x,y,z]$ with its natural grading and let $I=(x^3, y^2)$ be a homogeneous ideal of $R$. Now suppose I want to write down a graded free resolution of $I$, most examples I have seen being with the following, $$ F_2 \to R(-3) \oplus R(-2) \to I \to 0$$
I don't quite understand the need for the shifting, we want to preserve degree, but $R(-3) = R \cdot x^3$  and the map, at least on the first component takes $x^3 \to x^3$ and thus, at least to me, it seems as those the degree is preserved.

With the shifts, it seems as if we are taking $x^3 \in I$ to have degree zero as a generator of $I$, however, I don't understand why this would be the case.

I know this is a very basic question but the shifts have been a point of confusion for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we're dealing with graded rings and modules, all objects must come with a grading. It seems that the examples you've seen assume $x^3$ and $y^2$ lie in the zeroth part of the grading on $I$, but you need not assume this. In any case, grading is an extra piece of data attached to a module that you must keep track of. Some rings and modules have canonical gradings, but one is not restricted to choosing these.

Consider for example the polynomial ring $k[x]$. Although this is typically given the grading $g_0$ given by
$$k[x]= \bigoplus_{n=0}^{\infty} kx^n,$$
we may also consider the following grading $g_1$: $k[x]=A_0 \oplus A_1$, in which $A_0 = \bigoplus_{n=1}^{\infty} kx^{2n}$ and $A_1= \bigoplus_{n=1}^{\infty} kx^{2n+1}$. You may check that this is a grading on $k[x]$. If we take this grading however, then for some other graded ring $R$, a graded map $R \to (k[x], g_0)$ will not be the same thing as a graded map $R \to (k[x], g_1)$, in general. One may say similar things about modules.

Comment: A word for why we might want $x^3$ and $y^2$ to be in degree $0$ in $I$. If we consider the natural grading on $R/I$, then the images of $x^3$ and $y^2$ in $R/I$ are $0$, and hence lie in $(R/I)_0$.

Comment: Thank you for this clarification. I like your example of having the grading take place in the quotient, this makes sense now with what I have been reading.